# Docker and NETCore 2.0, unable to run docker image

Tags: windows, powershell, ubuntu, docker, asp.net-core

I have installed Docker on my windows machine. Currently I have my vsproject setup to where I can run the web application through Visual Studio's "Run with Docker" button.

But when I go into powershell and build my own image, using

```
docker build -t blog .
```

output:

```
PS C:\Users\Acina\sites\Blog> docker build -t blog .
unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: GetFileAttributesEx C:\Users\Acina\sites\Blog
\Dockerfile: The system cannot find the file specified.
PS C:\Users\Acina\sites\Blog> cd Blog
PS C:\Users\Acina\sites\Blog\Blog> docker build -t blog .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.584kB
Step 1/6 : FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
 ---> 452ca00e5495
Step 2/6 : ARG source
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 73e5e625c084
Step 3/6 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9cb30c8476e4
Step 4/6 : EXPOSE 80
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6d1a8f3cc094
Step 5/6 : COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/empty} .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> aedf4f7d5b5d
Step 6/6 : ENTRYPOINT dotnet Blog.dll
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d3d785062d3f
Successfully built d3d785062d3f
Successfully tagged blog:latest
SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host. All files and director
ies added to build context will have '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions f
or sensitive files and directories.
PS C:\Users\Acina\sites\Blog\Blog>
```

However, when I try to use: `docker run -p 5000:5000 blog`

```
PS C:\Users\Acina\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Blog\Blog> docker run -p 5000:5000 blog
[ERROR] docker : Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK from: 
[ERROR] At line:1 char:1
[ERROR] + docker run -p 5000:5000 blog
[ERROR] + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ERROR]     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Did you mean to...tnet SDK from: :String) [], Remote 
[ERROR]    Exception
[ERROR]     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
[ERROR]  
[ERROR]   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409
[ERROR]
```

From what I've researched so far, it seems that docker is unable to find my .dll file, which is located under Projects\Blog\Blog\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\Blog.dll

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
ARG source
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/empty} .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Blog.dll"]
```

Comment: Tag is `blog-site` and image is `blog`? Add the output of your `docker build` also

Comment: added the build output, I found a temporary workaround for the time being. I cloned the repo on my Linux server and ran `dotnet run` within Blog/Blog. I am using nginx to forward traffic to the localhost.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It looks like, dotnet core 2.0 doing before run `dotnet restore`. But this is problem, because for this you need SDK (microsoft/dotnet:2.0-sdk). So, if you want to development, you can simply replace runtime with sdk image. But, if you want production version, you can use this:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0-sdk
WORKDIR /app

# If you need to restore, publish etc...
#COPY *.csproj ./
#RUN dotnet restore

# build runtime image
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0-runtime 
WORKDIR /app
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/empty} .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Blog.dll"]
```

Here is original example with production solution: https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker-samples/tree/master/dotnetapp-prod

Hope it help!

Answer (score 0):

This is an artifact of the way that the Visual Studio "Docker" templating works - it assumes that the results of the builds are only used from Visual Studio.

I recommend checking out this [guide in the Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/aspnet-mssql-compose/). It shows how to do the Docker builds properly in containers.